# Azure Blob Storage - Error trying to delete blob with API REST with C#

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, http-status-code-403

I'm working with Azure Blob Storage and C#. I need to delete a blob using the API REST, but I get the 403 Forbidden error. I'm using the same function to generate the authentication header for create a new blob, but it works for put but doesn't it for delete. This is my code:

```
public bool DeleteBlob(string containerName, string fileName)
{
    string blobName = fileName;
    string method = "DELETE";
    string requestUri = $"https://{_accountName}.blob.core.windows.net/{containerName}/{blobName}";

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri);

    string now = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    request.Method = method;
    request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2020-10-02");
    request.Headers.Add("x-ms-date", now);
    request.Headers.Add("x-ms-delete-snapshots", "include");
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", AuthorizationHeader("DELETE", request, containerName, blobName));

    bool result = false;

    using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        if (resp.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.Accepted && resp.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            throw new Exception(resp.StatusDescription);
        }

        result = true;
    }

    return result;
}

private string AuthorizationHeader(string method, HttpWebRequest request, string containerName, string blobName)
{
    string urlResource = $"/{_accountName}/{containerName}/{blobName}";
    string stringToSign = $"{method}\n\n\n{request.ContentLength}\n\n{request.ContentType}\n\n\n\n\n\n\n{GetCanonicalizedHeaders(request)}{GetCanonicalizedResource(request.RequestUri, _accountName)}";

    HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(Convert.FromBase64String(_accountKey));
    string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign)));

    return string.Format("{0} {1}:{2}", "SharedKey", _accountName, signature);
}
    
private string GetAuthorizationHeader(string method, HttpWebRequest request, string now, string containerName, string blobName)
{
    string urlResource = $"/{_accountName}/{containerName}/{blobName}";

    var canonicalizedStringToBuild = string.Format("{0}\n{1}", now, $"/{_accountName}/" + urlResource);
    string signature;
    using (var hmac = new HMACSHA256(Convert.FromBase64String(_accountKey)))
    {
        byte[] dataToHmac = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(canonicalizedStringToBuild);
        signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(dataToHmac));
    }

    return string.Format($"{_accountName}:" + signature);
}
    
private string GetCanonicalizedHeaders(HttpWebRequest request)
{
    ArrayList headerNameList = new ArrayList();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (string headerName in request.Headers.Keys)
    {
        if (headerName.ToLowerInvariant().StartsWith("x-ms-", StringComparison.Ordinal))
        {
            headerNameList.Add(headerName.ToLowerInvariant());
        }
    }
    headerNameList.Sort();
    foreach (string headerName in headerNameList)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(headerName);
        string separator = ":";
        foreach (string headerValue in GetHeaderValues(request.Headers, headerName))
        {
            string trimmedValue = headerValue.Replace("\r\n", String.Empty);
            builder.Append(separator);
            builder.Append(trimmedValue);
            separator = ",";
        }
        sb.Append(builder.ToString());
        sb.Append("\n");
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
    
private string GetCanonicalizedResource(Uri address, string accountName)
{
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("/");
    builder.Append(accountName);
    builder.Append(address.AbsolutePath);
    str.Append(builder.ToString());
    NameValueCollection values2 = new NameValueCollection();

    if (address.Query.Length > 0)
    {
        string query = address.Query.Remove(0, 1);
        var queryParts = query.Split('&');
        foreach (var queryPart in queryParts)
        {
            var parts = queryPart.Split('=');

            values2.Add(parts[0], parts[1]);
        }

        ArrayList list2 = new ArrayList(values2.AllKeys);
        list2.Sort();
        foreach (string str3 in list2)
        {
            StringBuilder builder3 = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);
            builder3.Append(str3);
            builder3.Append(":");
            builder3.Append(values2[str3]);
            str.Append("\n");
            str.Append(builder3.ToString());
        }
    }

    return str.ToString();
}
```

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? As I commented for create a new blob working fine, but not for deletion. I don't know if the authentication header is different for delete (I know the method name is different) I have not found much information about that.
Thannks.

Comment: Is there a reason you're writing code to consume REST API instead of using .Net SDK?

Comment: Hi Gaurav. Thanks for your response.
Yes, there is a reason: I have to add this functionality in a Dynamics 365 custom workflow activity, and it is not possible add external assemblies to the code C# project. So I need to use the API REST. It is a system restriction.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your delete operation is failing with `403` error is because in your `stringToSign` you're assigning content length as `0` whereas it should be an empty string.

Please change your `AuthorizationHeader` method code to the code mentioned below and your delete blob operation should work just fine:

```
private string AuthorizationHeader(string method, HttpWebRequest request, string containerName, string blobName)
{
    string urlResource = $"/{_accountName}/{containerName}/{blobName}";
    var contentLength = request.ContentLength == 0 ? "" : request.ContentLength.ToString();
    string stringToSign = $"{method}\n\n\n{contentLength}\n\n{request.ContentType}\n\n\n\n\n\n\n{GetCanonicalizedHeaders(request)}{GetCanonicalizedResource(request.RequestUri, _accountName)}";

    HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(Convert.FromBase64String(_accountKey));
    string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign)));

    return string.Format("{0} {1}:{2}", "SharedKey", _accountName, signature);
}
```

What I have done above is set the content length value to an empty string if the content length is 0.

From this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key#blob-queue-and-file-services-shared-key-authorization) (emphasis mine):

> **In the current version, the Content-Length field must be an empty
> string if the content length of the request is zero**. In version
> 2014-02-14 and earlier, the content length was included even if zero.